# Error in SUM when unGROUPING

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a query that returns the SUM value of shipments from customers and its grouped by `shipment_id`. The values are correct.

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT((article.unit_price * article.tax)*shipment.amount)) as subtotal 
  FROM shipment 
 INNER JOIN customer ON customer.customer_id = shipment.customer_id 
 INNER JOIN article ON shipment.article_id = article.article_id 
 WHERE shipment.type_id = 2 
   AND shipment.customer_id = 947 
 GROUP BY shipment.shipment_id
```

When I remove GROUP BY to get the total value from the customer the value returned is incorrect.

Can someone help me figure this out, please?

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: 1 - Don't understand why you are summing distinct values. What if a customer has 2 of the same articles at the same price - surely you want them both in your sum. 2 - not clear why you are grouping by shipment_id when you are not selecting it - you may get several rows without knowing which is which.

Comment: Please show your table schema, sample data and expected results? Even better if you could create a sample in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/) :)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick responses. This is just a fragment of a bigger query and i´ve translated to english because i am portuguese. I´ll try to create a sample in SQLFIDDLE

Comment: @user1921592 Can you please take a look at this [refernce](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9da3d/6) to get going? I have created some sample data. So you can show us exactly where you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with your joins.  I can think of no situation where `sum(distinct )` makes sense in a query.  You are using it incorrectly.  What is happening is that you have duplicates articles across shipments, and the values are ok within a shipment (probably only one article in a shipment).  However, a different shipment has exactly the same article and the same amount.  The distinct removes such duplicates.

The solution is simple, just remove the `distinct`:

```
SELECT SUM((article.unit_price * article.tax)*shipment.amount) as subtotal 
FROM shipment INNER JOIN
     customer
     ON customer.customer_id = shipment.customer_id INNER JOIN
     article
     ON shipment.article_id = article.article_id 
WHERE shipment.type_id = 2 AND shipment.customer_id = 947
```